# Auxiliary table rows in one row

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Consider the following tables:

#### Daddy Table

```
daddy_id | daddy_name
       1 | daddyA
       2 | daddyB
```

---

#### Child Table

```
child_id | child_name | daddy_id
       1 | childA     | 1
       2 | childB     | 1
       3 | childC     | 1
       4 | childD     | 2
```

---

For extraordinary reasons I need some query that returns result sets like this:

#### Result set 1

```
daddy_id | daddy_name | child_id1 | child_id2 | child_id3 |
       1 | daddyA     | childA    | childB    | childC    |
```

#### Result set 2

```
daddy_id | daddy_name | child_id1
       2 | daddyB     | childD
```

My question is, should I keep try to achieve this? It's possible to achieve this just using C# and Sqlite?

**Note**: I'm using the generic [data reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of .NET framework 4.0 but needs some query that works with sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following query:

```
SELECT daddy_id,
       daddy_name,
       (SELECT group_concat(child_name)
        FROM children
        WHERE children.daddy_id = dads.daddy_id
       ) AS children
FROM dads
```

which would give you a result like this:

```
daddy_id | daddy_name | children
       1 | daddyA     | childA,childC,childB
       2 | daddyB     | childD
```

Comment: Very close to what I want. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the "extraordinary" reason is to databind the result to some UI component? Getting the query to return a variable number of columns is indeed not something you want to do, I doubt it is even possible, let alone maintainable.

In that case, why not perform the query and get a data reader with a fixed number of columns and process the data reader into another collection that you can use as data binding source.

Comment: Already tried something like that. I need those data at once because I'm using some yield returns.

Comment: Why not transform the ResultSet into an IEnumerable and return it directly instead of using yield return ?